# Detecting a dynamic class in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I need to detect that a class that is generated by another plugin exists and then execute some code. I can't seem to get it to work. It also needs to work in IE8.

Following is the code. I am using webshims which adds class="user-error" to the select box when there is an error. I need to detect that that class exists. Can anyone help?

```
<select id="Title" name="Title" required autofocus="autofocus" class="">
    <option value="" selected=yes> Title </option>
    <option value="Ms" > Ms </option>
            <option value="Mrs" > Mrs </option>
</select>

 var select = $('select');

$(select).each(function(){
  $(this).hasClass('user-error').css('background','#333');
});
```

Comment: For starters, why not just use: `$('.user-error').css('background','#333');`?

Comment: Your JS seems okay. Maybe it's being executed before the other code that adds the classes? And you can improve your JS: `$(select).filter('.user-error').css('background','#333');`

Comment: @pdoherty926 because OP wants to detect it...class is apply afterward not at DOM load..

Comment: @DipeshParmar right - which means even in its original form, this code will have to run inside of an onclick, onsubmit, etc. handler.

Comment: @user2696536 You didn't answer my question yet.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really use a click to do what I need :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. But you have typo in your code.

`$(this).hasClass('user-error').css('background','#333')` will not work because `$(this).hasClass('user-error')` will return boolean value `true` or `false`.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').filter('.user-error').css('background','#333');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4SStB/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Or simply `$(select).filter('.user-error').css('background','#333');`

Comment: You don't need `$(select)`, since `select` is already a jQuery object. It should just be `select.filter...`.

Comment: @Barmar updated code refers to `$('select')` instead of using separate variable `var select=$('select')`.

Comment: The code is in a doc ready function and it still doesn't work. I tried it with other dynamically created classes and the same thing...??

Comment: can you post your code and lib (that creating dynamic class) in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or post url.

Comment: Yeah sure...in this fiddle I create a class "focus" on the surrounding div of the select box. But if I go to add any CSS on that new class, it won't work: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnexH/12/). The library is webshims and it is a huge library, so won't add it in Fiddle

Comment: Still you have typo in your code see the latest code in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/KnexH/14/

Comment: Awesome..thanks, after some modifications to suit my needs, it worked a treat!

Comment: Can you tell me how I would not have it happen on all select boxes in the form but only the one that has focus? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnexH/16/)

Comment: Instead of changing all `select` elements class in `focusin` and `focusout` use `$(this)`.http://jsfiddle.net/KnexH/17/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    $(this).find('select.user-error').css('background','#333');
});
```

Comment: You can't be certain there are no other elements with this class except for `select` boxes.

Comment: @Itay But the OP is only iterating over `$('select')`, so other elements are irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar the original code in this answer was to handle every element with this class on the form.